# Is there a standard way for 3rd party to pay gas?

Tags: gas

A smart contract can be modified to provide, for each functions that allows a 3rd party to pay gas, an alternative of that function which takes a signed message and assume the signer to be the sender, therefore allowing any 3rd party to pay on behalf of the user.

I found at least 2 ways how this is implemented.

https://github.com/bokkypoobah/BokkyPooBahsTokenTeleportationServiceSmartContract

https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/875 where atomic swap can be done by a 3rd party.

Since smart contracts, once written, is difficult to update, what is the most standard way to write smart contract that allows 3rd party to pay the gas that is accepted by the majority?